# How to set Ringtone from raw folder resource

Tags: android

I see multiple threads about doing this but they all differ in their approaches. Can someone tell me the definitive way to take a raw resource (i.e. "song.mp3") and set it as the ringtone on a phone? I know it goes something like: 
1. Push the song to external storage.
2. Set ringtone using the absolute path of where the song saved in external storage.

But if someone has some java that shows how this plays out, that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this,May it helps

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packagename/raw/song.mp3");
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                    path);

            RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), path)
                    .play();
```

Comment: Rather than setting my Ringtone to the mp3 in my raw folder, this code just sets it to the default AT&T Ringtone on my phone. Do I need to export my sound to external storage first?

Comment: It is not working from raw folder. Any idea guys to set the ringtone directly from the raw folder?

Comment: Throws java.lang.SecurityException: com.ddwebapp.member was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS. This permission is only available for system apps